# Is it safe to update unrelated values in a Guava cache during a CacheLoader::load call?

Tags: java, guava, google-guava-cache

I want to store a cache of `{organizationId, userId} -> userEmail`, but the API available to me returns all emails for a given organization. So long as I'm getting all of these values, is it safe to store them all during a call to `CacheLoader::load`?

```
private final LoadingCache<Pair<UUID, UUID>, String> emailCache = CacheBuilder
        .newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(10000)
        .build(new CacheLoader<Pair<UUID, UUID>, String>() {
            @Override
            public String load(final Pair<UUID, UUID> key) throws Exception {
                final UUID orgId = key.getValue0();
                final List<User> users = remoteService.getAllUsers(orgId);
                final Map<Pair<UUID, UUID>, String> updates = new HashMap<>();
                for (User user : users) {
                    updates.put(Pair.with(orgId, user.getId()), user.getEmail());
                }

                // is this safe?
                emailCache.putAll(updates);

                return updates.get(key);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Maybe instead use the orgId as the key and an immutable map as the value. Then use a weigher based on the map's size. This will let you keep the bulk items, but evict the whole map and may consume too much  space for low valued mappings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't, as that can cause races.  On the other hand, it is safe to do this with CacheLoader.loadAll, which specifically documents that it can return a map with more entries than were requested.